# Downsampling 48khz to 16khz - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-audio-api, getusermedia

At the moment `getUserMedia` is getting audio (from a mic) at 48Khz. But my speech-recognition server could only use audio at 16Khz (could be 48Khz but it will do down-sampling). My objective is to save bandwidth doing the down-sampling on the client side.

```
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
    if(!recording) return;
    console.log ('recording');
    left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));//write to server

  }

function convertoFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
  var l = buffer.length;
  var buf = new Int16Array(l)

  while (l--) {
    if(l%3==0){
    buf[l/3] = buffer[l]*0xFFFF;
  }
  }
  return buf.buffer
}
```

Any other implementations from you?
EDIT:
I put the nodejs server recording the same audio to a file and then I open it with matlab. The files have the same size. And shouldn't, right?

Matlab plots - 16k

[image]

Matlab plots - 48k

[image: 48khz]

Comment: Since you don't really have an issue but you are seeking for a confirmation, i'd say your post belongs to codereview, not stackoverflow. Voting to close here. (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the data is being written to a stereo file, right? That could explain the choppy waveform, since you only have the data for the left channel and the right channel is filled with zeroes.

Also, you're creating your Int16Array() to be the length of the original buffer, but it should really only be a third of the length, since you only use every third sample. That'd probably explain why they're the same size once you've rendered it.

I'm not sure how to interpret matlab plots, but that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: And you can't just take every third sample.  You need to do some filtering otherwise the resulting audio will sound strange.  Unless you already know that the input is band-limited to 16 kHz.  You can use WebAudio to do the filtering for you.

Comment: yes I know about that @RaymondToy ... I want to do exactly that, a "brute" downsampling. Because after doing that in matlab and using it speech-recognizer it will works fine.

Comment: @OskarEriksson thanks for your tip... I missed that size issue

Answer (score 2):

The solution (thanks @OskarEriksson, this is your tip and now I have no problems):

```
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
    if(!recording) return;
    console.log ('recording');
    left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));//write to server

  }

function convertoFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
  var l = buffer.length;
  var buf = new Int16Array(l/3); //<-----Only change here

  while (l--) {
    if(l%3==0){
    buf[l/3] = buffer[l]*0xFFFF;
  }
  }
  return buf.buffer
}
```

The Matlab Plots:
48k
[image]

16k

[image]

Note: The word that I spell is exactly the same, but you can see some delay because of browser switching, and press Start\Stop button.